# Docker - Install PHP 5.2.17 and php-gd

Tags: php, apache, docker, gd, phplot

I am migrating an extremely old and legacy system written in PHP. Currently I have made good progress, however, the code makes use of a library called PHPLot where it is dependent on php-gd.

I've done everything ... I've been trying to install this dependence for 3 days. Can you help me?

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM httpd:2.2

MAINTAINER Marcus Campos <campos.v.marcus@gmail.com>

ENV HTTPD_CONF $HTTPD_PREFIX/conf/httpd.conf
ENV PHP_INI /usr/local/lib/php.ini
ENV HOME /root

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data && groupmod -g 1000 www-data \
    && sed -i 's/User daemon/User www-data/' $HTTPD_CONF \
    && sed -i 's/Group daemon/Group www-data/' $HTTPD_CONF

WORKDIR $HOME

ADD http://www.geocities.jp/aoba_suzukaze/php-5.2.17.tar.bz2 .
ADD http://www.geocities.jp/aoba_suzukaze/libxml29_compat.patch .

RUN echo 'ServerName localhost:80' >> $HTTPD_CONF

RUN apt-get update && apt install -y --no-install-recommends bzip2 gcc     make libxml2-dev libmysqlclient-dev patch autoconf

RUN ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so \
    && ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.a

RUN set -x \
    && tar -xf php-5.2.17.tar.bz2 \
    && cd php-5.2.17 \
    && patch -p0 < $HOME/libxml29_compat.patch \
    && ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql --with-mysqli --with-pdo-mysql --enable-mbstring \
    && make -j"$(nproc)" \
    && make install \
    && cp php.ini-recommended $PHP_INI

RUN echo '<FilesMatch \.php$>' >> $HTTPD_CONF \
    && echo '    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php' >> $HTTPD_CONF \
    && echo '</FilesMatch>' >> $HTTPD_CONF

RUN sed -i 's/"GPCS"/"EGPCS"/' $PHP_INI

RUN pecl install xdebug-2.2.7 \
    && echo 'zend_extension="/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/xdebug.so"' >> $PHP_INI \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_enable=On' >> $PHP_INI \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_connect_back=On' >> $PHP_INI \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_autostart=On' >> $PHP_INI \
    && echo 'xdebug.idekey="xdebug"' >> $PHP_INI

WORKDIR $HTTPD_PREFIX/htdocs/
```

UPDATE:

I was able to solve the problem. Here's my code with the solution:

```
FROM httpd:2.2

MAINTAINER Marcus Campos <campos.v.marcus@gmail.com>

ENV HTTPD_CONF $HTTPD_PREFIX/conf/httpd.conf
ENV PHP_INI /usr/local/lib/php.ini
ENV HOME /root

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data && groupmod -g 1000 www-data \
    && sed -i 's/User daemon/User www-data/' $HTTPD_CONF \
    && sed -i 's/Group daemon/Group www-data/' $HTTPD_CONF

WORKDIR $HOME

ADD http://www.geocities.jp/aoba_suzukaze/php-5.2.17.tar.bz2 .
ADD http://www.geocities.jp/aoba_suzukaze/libxml29_compat.patch .

RUN echo 'ServerName localhost:80' >> $HTTPD_CONF

RUN apt-get update && apt install -y --no-install-recommends bzip2 gcc make libxml2-dev libmysqlclient-dev patch autoconf libjpeg-dev libpng12-dev

RUN ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so \
    && ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.a

RUN set -x \
    && ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.a /usr/lib/libjpeg.a \
    && ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/libjpeg.so \
    && ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.a /usr/lib/libpng.a \
    && ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so /usr/lib/libpng.so \
    && tar -xf php-5.2.17.tar.bz2 \
    && cd php-5.2.17 \
    && patch -p0 < $HOME/libxml29_compat.patch \
    && ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql --with-mysqli --with-pdo-mysql --enable-mbstring \
    && make -j"$(nproc)" \
    && make install \
    && cp php.ini-recommended $PHP_INI

RUN echo '<FilesMatch \.php$>' >> $HTTPD_CONF \
    && echo '    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php' >> $HTTPD_CONF \
    && echo '</FilesMatch>' >> $HTTPD_CONF

RUN sed -i 's/"GPCS"/"EGPCS"/' $PHP_INI

RUN pecl install xdebug-2.2.7 \
    && echo 'zend_extension="/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/xdebug.so"' >> $PHP_INI \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_enable=On' >> $PHP_INI \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_connect_back=On' >> $PHP_INI \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_autostart=On' >> $PHP_INI \
    && echo 'xdebug.idekey="xdebug"' >> $PHP_INI

WORKDIR $HTTPD_PREFIX/htdocs/
```

Comment: The library you mentioned isn't an extension, but a library. What's the above got to do with it exactly?

Comment: This is true. I need to install the gd.so extension... I researched the internet and in the past, you could run apt-get install php5-gd to install but today this does not work anymore.

Comment: May I suggest you use [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) for your task? I believe your issue would go away quite easily with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your ./configure line:

To enable GD-support configure PHP --with-gd[=DIR] , where DIR is the GD base install directory. To use the recommended bundled version of the GD library, use the configure option --with-gd . GD library requires libpng and libjpeg to compile.

http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php

Comment: Where do I find these libs?

Comment: You should just be able to add --with-gd on your configure line. Does that not work? If not apt-get install gd

Comment: The bash returns 'configure: error: libpng.(a|so) not found.'

Comment: ok that's fine, `apt-get install libpng` and `apt-get install libjpeg` above the gd line

Comment: No probs amigo! All the best!